# Vue. Global vs local distribution of reusable options

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

As far as i understand there are two main ways to reuse options in different components.

Global registration of plugin or mixin making the desired options to be available all over application.

```
Vue.use(VuePlugin)
```

Or register them locally in every component where needed.

```
var Component = Vue.extend({ mixins: [VueMixin] })
```

Obviously the first method makes your code cleaner and easier to maintain. But which one is more efficient in terms of bundle size and overall application efficiency?

Comment: Are you using webpack or some bundling tool?

Comment: @Dencio I do use webpack. Though the question is environment agnostic. At list if it can be so...